# Script executed as other user from root creates files in wrong directory (root)

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, su

I'm running a bash script from a root perspective which then starts a program in the script

```
su -c "sh /home/user2/script.sh" -m user2
```

The problem is that the program started by this script, while executed as *user2*, is still trying to create files in */root/.config/*, which of course fails as it's not permitted by *user2*.

Am I doing anything wrong? Is is there another better way to actually change user in the script, enter the user's password then start the program?

Comment: The `-m` parameter preserves the calling shell's environment, so `$HOME` will remain set to `/root` if called from a root shell. Why have you used it? And why are you calling the Bourne shell to run a `bash` script?

Comment: Oh wow thanks.. I thought the "m" parameter was too specify the user, totally misunderstood as I took that command from another stash overflow question.

Comment: About the Bourne shell.. that's all I ever used, didn't know I shouldn't always use it

Comment: Your question is tagged with `[bash]` and it begins with "I'm running a bash script ...". It is unusual these days not to use Bash, as that is the default shell with most Linux distributions. If your script begins with `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh`, that will determine which shell is used, regardless of the shell it was launched from. In passing, it is common for `sh` and `bash` to be the same program, with switches to define which syntax to use. I'll answer your question, so that others can see that there is an answer,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `-m` parameter with `su`, it will pass your current environment to the command or shell being executed. In particular, the `$HOME` variable will be set to its value in the calling shell and not determined by the user invoked.

So, if you're logged in as `root`, `$HOME` will be `/root` and remain so when executing `script.sh` under `su -m`. Unless there are other parts of the environment that you want to preserve, you can simply omit the `-m` from the `su` call.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! +1 for the full explanations, hope someone can use that. I've been using Linux for a while but as an amateur so I don't know about the details like this, very helpful!